# word counter for Textarea in Django Form

Tags: django-forms

I am just starting out in django. I want to integrate a maximum word counter into Textarea of my django form. I have been looking into many sources, but I have become all the more confused.

I would really appreciate any suggestions. (I know how to write a javascript for a word counter for plain html forms). The main confusion for me is how to add something like the "onClick" attribute to fields in django forms.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's `.onChange()` to trigger the word counter. As you can probably guess this will let you call a function every time a change is made to the textfield.

As for the word counter itself, a basic concept would be

1. get the value of the textfield
2. split the string into an array using spaces " " as a delimiter
3. count how long the array is

If you need help with code I could give you some pointers. I would use jQuery for all of this as it's the most versatile library i've come across for this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I have done precisely that. I used jQuery for client validation; If javascript is side-stepped by chance, I made a server-side validation.